# The remote server returned an error (400) Bad Request using webrequest

Tags: asp.net, httpwebrequest

When I execute HttpWebRequest.GetResponse on URL, GetResponse returns "The remote server returned an error:  (400) Bad Request." instead of response.

The strange thing is that when I run this url at the browser I get the **right response**.

doesn't webrequest need to return the same values as the browser?

the following code return bad request

```
 // Create a request for the URL. 
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(
              "http://someUrl/api/v5/basicAuth");


            // Get the response.
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            // Display the status.
            Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
            // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            // Read the content.
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            // Display the content.
            Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
            // Clean up the streams and the response.
            reader.Close();
            response.Close();
```

also tried  using  WebClient with same results.

any idea how to get the proper response same as the browser?

Answer (score 0):

The title says you're getting a 400 bad request, but in your question you say 404 Not Found.  Those are very different. For a 404, I'd be troubleshooting the URL itself and how the request is being routed, DNS, etc.  if it's a 400, then I would use something like Fiddler to capture how my request looks when using a browser, then see what the request looks like when coming from the program and see what's different/missing.  It could be that some HTTP headers are needed, such as the content-type, or handling of cookies, etc etc.  But something like Fiddler could at least get you started.

Comment: yes you right 400 error when try simple WebRequest as shown above.and I get 404 when trying to post some data to this url.

Comment: So how are you "supposed" to interact with the URL?  Is this a web service that responds only to GET, POST, PUT, etc?  If you can get to it successfully with a browser and see data, then I presume GET works.  So I'd try Fiddler to see what the differences are between your browser request and the HttpWebRequest from your code.

Comment: yes it's a web service that responds to GET, POST.I will check the Fiddler to see the Differences.thanks

Comment: You should also be able to use Fiddler's "Composer" to create POST requests for further troubleshooting.  Firefox also has an add-on called Posterizer that does something similar.

Comment: Did you have any luck seeing the differences with Fiddler?  Did you figure out the issue?